# How to set the banner inside a container?

Tags: flutter, banner

I am working with flutter. I am trying to add a banner across the container as shown in the image. The have some padding I gave.so it is affect the correct fitting of banner. How I do this banner without affecting the padding of the container like showing in the picture?

Comment: Where is the picture ?? Please add the image

Answer (score 0):

Add css object fit:

```
img {
object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a container element with the desired width and center it on the page.
Inside the container, position the banner element using CSS, ensuring it's centered both horizontally and vertically.
Customize the banner's appearance, such as background color and text color, to suit your design.
Add your banner content, such as text or additional elements, inside the banner element.

Comment: title question will good if there is have 1 word thats explain the engine for example on flutter. and the answer is for a website not for flutter/dart where there is no CSS.